# Correlated Sub-Query: "the percentage value of its stock on hand as a percentage of the stock on hand for product line "

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Full Question**: Report for each product, the percentage value of its stock on hand as a percentage of the stock on hand for product line to which it belongs. Order the report by product line and percentage value within product line descending. Show percentages with two decimal places.

Database: http://richardtwatson.com/dm6e/images/general/ClassicModels.png

My attempt...

```
SELECT P.productCode, ((P.quantityinStock* '100,2') / (SELECT MAX(P.quantityInStock)
FROM Products P)) AS Percent_ 
FROM Products P 
WHERE P.productCode= (SELECT ((COUNT(Q.productLine *100.0))) / (SELECT MAX(Q.productLine))
FROM ProductLines Q
WHERE Q.productLine= P.productCode 
ORDER BY Q.productLine DESC)
```

i am struggling quite a bit with these correlated subqueries!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this you want?

```
;WITH Products(productCode,quantityinStock,productLine) AS (
     SELECT 'Product1',20,'Line1' UNION ALL
     SELECT 'Product2',60,'Line1' UNION ALL
     SELECT 'Product3',30,'Line2' UNION ALL
     SELECT 'Product4',30,'Line2' UNION ALL
     SELECT 'Product5',30,'Line2' 
 )
SELECT P.*,ROUND(P.quantityinStock*1.0/SUM(P.quantityInStock)OVER(PARTITION BY p.productLine)*100,2) AS StockPercent
FROM Products P 
ORDER BY p.productLine desc
```

```
productCode quantityinStock productLine StockPercent
----------- --------------- ----------- ---------------------------------------
Product4    30              Line2       33.330000000000
Product5    30              Line2       33.330000000000
Product3    30              Line2       33.330000000000
Product2    60              Line1       75.000000000000
Product1    20              Line1       25.000000000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to get the answer, although it does not use correlated subqueries, and I'll leave the ordering and display to two decimal places up to you:

```
Select ...
    p.QuantityInStock * 100.0 / l.LineQtyInStock As [Percent]
  From #product As p
  Join (
    Select Sum(QuantityInStock) As LineQtyInStock,
        ProductLine 
      From #product
      Group By ProductLine) As l On p.ProductLine = l.ProductLine;
```

You got into a bit of trouble when you tried to use `MAX()` which would return the highest `quantityInStock` , when you actually want a `SUM()` of the quantities by `productLine`.